# How to Specify the Layout When Attaching a PDF to an Email Using Wicked PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, actionmailer, wicked-pdf

I am unable to get an email to generate when I try to specify a layout for a pdf I want to attach to an email using Wicked PDF. This is a rails 4 app.

When I use the following code, the application successfully sends the email with the pdf attachment, but without the desired styling:

```
def invoice_created(invoice_id)
  @invoice = Invoice.find(invoice_id)
  @subscription = Subscription.find(@invoice.subscription_id)
  attachments['invoice.pdf'] = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
    render_to_string(:pdf => "invoice", :template => 'invoices/show.pdf.erb'))
  mail(to: 'you@example.com', subject: "Your Invoice is Ready")
end
```

But when I add the layout, nothing generates.

```
def invoice_created(invoice_id)
  @invoice = Invoice.find(invoice_id)
  @subscription = Subscription.find(@invoice.subscription_id)
  attachments['invoice.pdf'] = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
    render_to_string(:pdf => "invoice", 
                     :template => 'invoices/show.pdf.erb', 
                     :layout => 'pdf.html.erb'))
  mail(to: 'you@example.com', subject: "Your Invoice is Ready")
end
```

In my controller, I display the pdf in the browser and it correctly uses the pdf.html.erb layout:

```
def show
  @invoice = current_account.invoices.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
      render :pdf => 'file_name',
      :template => 'invoices/show.pdf.erb',
      :layout => 'pdf.html.erb'
    end
  end
end
```

I'm not seeing any obvious errors in the dev log, other than the email file not being created.

I am seeing the following so it looks like it sees the layout but won't show it.

```
Rendered invoices/show.pdf.erb within layouts/pdf.html.erb (13.7ms)
```

Could there a problem with conflicting layouts?

If I try to generate several emails with the layout specified, then remove the layout code from the mailer, restart the server, request a new email, then the emails I previously requested get sent.

I tried adding

```
:show_as_html => params[:debug].present?
```

to the mailer to see if it would shed some light but this also caused the email not to be sent.

Comment: it's very strange. Especialy the thing, that it sends the mails at the end. idk, something not closing io streams properly? You can check the generated mails with http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#action-mailer-previews
Would you like to submit some demo code on github? we can check if the issue can be reproduced and file a bug report to rails or wicked_pdf

Comment: It would be also intereseting to check wether the pdf can be saved to the filesystem by using render_to_string https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf#super-advanced-usage

Comment: Thanks for idea to post an example to github. For some reason the error wasn't raised in my configuration. The basic app I built raised the issue, and the solution right away. https://github.com/stevejc/WickedPDF-Example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem code was in pdf layout:

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Not sure why I didn't receive any error messages in my app. I have my application set up to display errors with `gem 'better_errors'` which didn't display any errors. I set up a new application just to play with wicked_pdf, but didn add better_errors to the gem file.

Now I received the following error message:

```
undefined method `protect_against_forgery?'
```

Once this line was removed from the `layouts/pdf/html.erb` file the app correctly attached the styled pdf.

Here's a link to the sample wicked_pdf example I used to find the solution: https://github.com/stevejc/WickedPDF-Example